# Split rows based on color of the cell and deconstruct comma separated string

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to Split two rows based on the Color cell value. Each comma-separated value should generate a new row.

Google Sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rwtSxDn_gf60xy0w63mp8Dj4bMUH9tNKJjtnsbqGzTw/edit?usp=sharing

The formula should create the rows E5:G8 form the rows A5:C6.

The formula should work with any number of rows.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and provide [mcve]. And if you receive an answer that helps you to resolve your problem please check it off so that everyone can see that the problem is resolved. Generally, we like to see the code that you have are having a problem with and a description of what you have tried. If you successfully integrate all of these suggestions into your question then your much more likely to get a quick resolution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know formulas much but can write a script so I did. This code reads the left cols then writes the right cols. If sheet formatting changes, will need changes in code. Copy/paste this function into a script and run the `test` function. If it works, can be run from a custom menu instead of using a formula. If it doesn't work, paste here the error and I'll try to debug.

```
function test() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // 5th row to start, 1st col to start, sheet.getLastRow()-4 is the num of rows to read, 3 cols to read
  // [ row, row ... ]
  var left = sheet.getRange(5, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 4, 3).getValues();
  // filter empty rows
  left = left.filter(function(row) {
    return row.every(function(el) {
      return el != '';
    });
  });
  // hold rows to insert
  // will be [ row, row... ]
  var right = [];
  // for each row create row to insert right
  left.forEach(function(row) {
    var item = row[0];
    var colors = row[1].split(',');
    var price = row[2];
    colors.forEach(function(c) {
      // create row, [item, color, price]
      right.push([item, c, price]);
    });
  });
  // insert rows to right
  // 5th row to start, 5th col to start, right.length is the num of rows to insert, 3 cols to write
  sheet.getRange(5, 5, right.length, 3).setValues(right);
}
```